# Modeling a linear system with Python

Tags: simulation, python, modeling

I would like to simulate/model a closed-loop, linear, time-invariant system (specifically a locked PLL approximation) with python.

Each sub-block within the model has a known transfer function which is given in terms of complex frequency `H(s) = K / ( s * tau + 1 )`.  Using the model, I would like to see how the system response as well as the noise response is affected as parameters (e.g. the VCO gain) are changed.  This would involve using Bode plots and root-locus plots.

How can I do this with Python?

Comment: Electrical Engineering is for questions about designing and implementing linear systems, not for their simulation and modeling; that's a topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Regrettably, MathJax/LaTeX isn't available on Stack Overflow; thanks for using it here but I'm editing it out for migration.

Comment: [scipy](https://scipy.org/ "scipy") and [numpy](https://numpy.org/) modules are suited for your application.

Comment: While I don't believe it (or any Python modules) contain "canned" Bode or root-locus plots, you should be able to generate your own suitable 2-D plots using [matplotlib](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/) with Python.

Comment: I know and use scipy and numpy, but surely there is something more specific and targeted for linear system modeling. It may be a sub-module of numpy/scipy???

Comment: @KevinVermeer I am "designing and implementing" a linear system, but I'm using python to help, so I guess I don't understand why I was migrated.  I thought I would get more help where more EE types hang out.

Comment: @benpro - Your question was "What Python modules should I seek out to get the job done", which is very definitely a Stack Overflow question. Many of the EE types hang out on Stack Overflow as well; I'm sorry that your're getting poor answers for now but this is a question for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.bode.html
you can now use this:

```
from scipy import signal
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

s1 = signal.lti([1], [1, 1])
w, mag, phase = signal.bode(s1)

plt.figure()
plt.semilogx(w, mag)    # bode magnitude plot
plt.figure()
plt.semilogx(w, phase)  # bode phase plot
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 12):

I know this is a bit old, but a search brought me to this question.  I put this together when I couldn't find a good module for it.  It's not much, but it's a good start if somebody else finds themselves here.

```
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
import numpy as np
import scipy.signal

def bode(G,f=np.arange(.01,100,.01)):
    plt.figure()
    jw = 2*np.pi*f*1j
    y = np.polyval(G.num, jw) / np.polyval(G.den, jw)
    mag = 20.0*np.log10(abs(y))
    phase = np.arctan2(y.imag, y.real)*180.0/np.pi % 360

    plt.subplot(211)
    #plt.semilogx(jw.imag, mag)
    plt.semilogx(f,mag)
    plt.grid()
    plt.gca().xaxis.grid(True, which='minor')

    plt.ylabel(r'Magnitude (db)')

    plt.subplot(212)
    #plt.semilogx(jw.imag, phase)
    plt.semilogx(f,phase)
    plt.grid()
    plt.gca().xaxis.grid(True, which='minor')
    plt.ylabel(r'Phase (deg)')
    plt.yticks(np.arange(0, phase.min()-30, -30))

    return mag, phase

f=scipy.signal.lti([1],[1,1])
bode(f)
```

Edit:  I am back here because somebody upvoted this answer, you should try [Control Systems Library](http://www.cds.caltech.edu/~murray/wiki/index.php/Control_Systems_Library_for_Python).  They have implemented the bulk of the Matlab control systems toolbox with matching syntax and everything.

Comment: I accepted this answer after the edit about the Control Systems Library.

Answer (score 4):

As @Matt said, I know this is old. But this came up as my first google hit, so I wanted to edit it.

You can use `scipy.signal.lti` to model linear, time invariant systems. That gives you `lti.bode`.

For an impulse response in the form of H(s) = (As^2 + Bs + C)/(Ds^2 + Es + F), you would enter `h = scipy.signal.lti([A,B,C],[D,E,F])`. To get the bode plot, you would do `plot(*h.bode()[:2])`.

Answer (score 4):

I got Bode plots working out this way, using python-control.

```
from matplotlib.pyplot import * # Grab MATLAB plotting functions
from control.matlab import *    # MATLAB-like functions


# Transfer functions for dynamics
G_modele = tf([1], [13500, 345, 1]);

# Use state space versions
G_modele = tf2ss(G_modele);

figure(1); 
bode(G_modele, dB=1);
show();
```

The code was mainly taken from this example which is very extensive

http://www.cds.caltech.edu/~murray/wiki/index.php/Python-control/Example:_Vertical_takeoff_and_landing_aircraft